# Phpmailer gmail SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to get PHPMailer work but keep getting `SMTP connect() failed` error.
I end up just using the gmail example provided in the [github repository](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) but still doesn't work.

I've set `SMTPDebug` to `4` and here's error message:

```
Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Things I've tried but didn't work:

both IIS and WAMP on my local

set open_ssl to enable

Comment: are they setup properly?  if not it's not a PHP issue, since you say both are setup locally.

Comment: I know it is very likely a network / server issue so I already tried different server and trying a different network. But I still don't have any idea how to troubleshoot them. Any suggestion will be very appreciate.

Comment: The error `10060` you are getting is a timeout error but you should be able to connect to smtp.gmail.com port 587 so it does appear to be a network or firewall error.  The simplest way to test is from a console try to open a telnet connection `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` and see what happens.  It should connect and give you a banner like `220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP qc16sm6287151pab.47 - gsmtp` upon connecting.  If you can't connect via telnet see if it is a DNS or firewall issue.

Comment: yeah ,`telnet` says timeout and there it seems a firewall issue. I uploaded the example to another server and every thing works fine. Thanks.